# Anaconda navigator crashes

Tags: anaconda, ubuntu-16.04

This is the error I'm getting:-

> File
>   "/home/gunjan/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/widgets/tabs/community.py",
>   line 372, in set_content_list
>       uri=item['uri'], date=item.get('date', '') or "", KeyError: 'uri' Aborted (core dumped)

This is what I get from conda info:
Current conda install:

```
           platform : linux-64
      conda version : 4.2.9
   conda is private : False
  conda-env version : 4.2.9
conda-build version : 2.0.2
     python version : 3.5.2.final.0
   requests version : 2.11.1
   root environment : /home/gunjan/anaconda3  (writable)
default environment : /home/gunjan/anaconda3
   envs directories : /home/gunjan/anaconda3/envs
      package cache : /home/gunjan/anaconda3/pkgs
       channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64/
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
        config file : None
       offline mode : False
```

Comment: Could you provide some more context to the error please?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same problem. Just update anaconda-navigator

```
conda update anaconda-navigator
```

After successful update, you can run

```
anaconda-navigator
```